# "I can see someone " vs "I see someone"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

As this [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/can) says *can* is used with the verbs *see*, *hear*, *feel*, *taste*, and *smell*, and with verbs connected with thinking, to mean that someone sees something, hears something etc. For exapmple:

> Here they are – I **can** see their car.
>
> I **can’t** understand why you’re so upset.
>
> **Can** you smell something burning?

But what if I omit can from the sentences, for example:

> Here they are – I see their car.
>
> I don't understand why you’re so upset.
>
> Do you smell something burning?

Is there is any difference in meaning between the sentences? If there is, then help me to see one please.

Comment: Your second two sentences are poor examples of what (I think) you're asking because you're not ***just*** removing *can*, you're actually replacing it with something else. That's *different* from what the title of your question is asking—and also different from the scenario given in your first sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that in your examples there is **no difference**. Because people will interpret it correctly. But strictly speaking when you add *can* it could point to someone having an ability to do a certain thing, and adding the word **can** would thus change the meaning of the sentence..

For example:

> I can see colours

and

> I see colours

The first one would mean that I have normal vision and can see / distinguish colours. But the second one means that I am seeing colours *at this moment*.